# ¿Como eliminar registros unicos(que no se repiten) de una tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes registros
1
2
2
3
4
4
5
quiero  hacer una consulta que solo me de como resultado
2
2
4
4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu tabla luce similar a esto:

```
select * from names;
+----+-------+
| id | field |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  4 |     3 |
|  5 |     4 |
|  6 |     4 |
|  7 |     5 |
+----+-------+
```

Con la siguiente agregación agrupamos por el campo `field` y con `having` aplicamos una condición más (se repite más de una vez):

```
select field from names group by field having count(field) > 1;
+-------+
| field |
+-------+
|     2 |
|     4 |
+-------+
```

Para obtener el id de los que se repiten:

```
select * from names where field in (select field from names group by field having count(field) > 1);
+----+-------+
| id | field |
+----+-------+
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  5 |     4 |
|  6 |     4 |
+----+-------+
```

Para obtener los registros que no se repiten podemos realizarlo con la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from names where field in (select field from names group by field having count(field) = 1);
+----+-------+
| id | field |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  4 |     3 |
|  7 |     5 |
+----+-------+
```

Y para eliminarlos necesitamos usar una tabla temporal, ya que no podemos ejecutar `delete` con agregaciones sobre la misma tabla:

```
create temporary table temp select * from names where field in (select field from names group by field having count(field) = 1);
```

Después ejecutamos el `delete`:

```
delete from names where id in (select id from temp);
```

Por lo que la tabla queda de esta manera:

```
select * from names;
+----+-------+
| id | field |
+----+-------+
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  5 |     4 |
|  6 |     4 |
+----+-------+
```

Si todo esta bien procedemos a eliminar la tabla temp:

```
drop temporary table temp;
```

- En las agregaciones (como agrupar) se usa `having` en lugar de `where`.
- fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10554764/3399874

Comment: Excelente, ahora una pregunta mas, si quiero eliminar esos registros que solo aparecen una sola ves y quedarme con los que se repiten como le hago?